# x86 How to add all the positive integers in an array

Tags: assembly, x86, sum

I have this code below, and this seems to be adding up ALL the integers in an array, instead of taking ONLY the positive. I'm kind of confused how to fix this problem as I am new to x86 Assembly Programming. Thank you for your help!

```
int addpos(int* X, int length){
    __asm{
        PUSH ebx
        PUSH ecx
        PUSH edx
        PUSH esi
        PUSH edi
        MOV ebx, X
        MOV ecx, length

        xor eax, eax
     L1:
        cmp ecx, 0
        add eax, [ebx]
        add ebx, 4
        loop L1

        POP edi
        POP esi
        POP edx
        POP ecx
        POP ebx
    }
}
```

Comment: removing the content of your question doesn't help anybody. It removes the *context* of the Q&A format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably more efficient variations, but the following should do:

```
    xor  eax, eax    ; total = 0
L1:
    mov  esi, [ebx]  ; X[i]
    add  ebx, 4      ; or: lea ebx, [ebx + 4]
    test esi, esi
    js   L2          ; jump if sign (most significant) bit set.
    add  eax, esi    ; total += X[i]
L2:
    loop L1
```

This may not be the best way to structure the loop - and it assumes that: `length (ecx) != 0`